# Inject global twig variables in custom twig_variable.yml

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to inject global variables to be used in the twig files.

I know I can add them to config.yml

```
twig:
   variable_1: variable 1
   variable_2: variable 2
```

but with the current setup I am not able to update the config.yml.

I have injected the yml file via load() inside the extension class inside DependencyInjection but that's as far as I got because I don't know how to then inject it for Twig use.

Comment: hi @user742736 have you found a solutions? What do you think about the approach described in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try replicate the logic of the TwigExtensionLoader as defined [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/TwigExtension.php#L115) in a compilerPass, as example:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $def = $container->getDefinition('twig');
    $def->addMethodCall('addGlobal', array('my-key', 'my-value'));
}
```

**More Detailed example:**

Suppose we have a loaded properties as follow:

<kbd>twig_params.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
    foo: bar
```

Already loaded by the DependencyInjection we can add a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-separate-compiler-passes), as example:

<kbd>CustomPass</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CustomPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $foo = $container->getParameter('foo');

        $def = $container->getDefinition('twig');
        $def->addMethodCall('addGlobal', array('foo', $foo));
    }
}
```

[See the docs here about](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) how to register it.

Then you can use in a twig template as usual global variables:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Hope this help